# Infinity equality

Tags: math, infinity

I'm wondering about following question, if infinity equals infinity (in a computer) and negative infinity equals negative infinity, why does the last sentence of the following snippet return false?

```
In [2]: math.inf == math.inf
Out[2]: True

In [3]: -math.inf == -math.inf
Out[3]: True

In [4]: (-math.inf) + (math.inf) == (-math.inf) + (math.inf)
Out[4]: False

In [5]:
```

I tried with several languages (C++, Javascript and Haskell) and all results are the same. I supposed it is something related to x86_64 architecture, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `(-math.inf) + (math.inf) ` is `NaN`, and `NaN` is not equal to itself. The link explains the rationale.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you would hope for the computer to return. As an example, consider `x**2 - x`. The function is `inf-inf` as x goes to infinity, but the answer is infinite rather than 0.

Terms like `inf - inf` are known as indeterminate. The answer can actually be any real number (or \pm infinity)